# Determining the number of square decompositions of a given number

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Can we determine how many decompositions of $n$ into two squares ($n=a^2+b^2$) there are, depending on how many factors of the form $4k+1$ there are? For a simple case, say square-free $n=\prod_{i=1}^k{p_i}$, is there a formula that gives the number of distinct sums that depends on $k$?

Comment: yes, in Dickson's little 1929 Intro book

Comment: [Sum of squares function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_squares_function)

Answer (score 2):

Let $$f(n)=\left|\{\,(a,b)\in\Bbb Z^2\mid a^2+b^2 =n\,\}\right|=\left|\{\,z\in\Bbb Z[i]\mid z\bar z =n\,\}\right|.$$
Every prime $p\equiv 1\pmod 4$ has an *essentially* unique representation as $p=a^2+b^2$, or more usefully: there is *essentially* a single Gaussian integer $z=a+bi\in\Bbb Z[i]$ with $z\bar z=p$. With full counting, we of course have eight possibilities: $z, iz, -z, -iz, \bar z, i\bar z, -\bar z, -i\bar z$. Thus
$$ f(p)=8\qquad p\equiv 1\pmod 4.$$
Generalized to powers of such $p$, we have
$$ f(p^r)=4(r+1),$$
obtained from $i^kz^s\bar z^{r-s}$ with $0\le k<4$ and $0\le s\le r$.

On the other hand, for primes $p\equiv -1\pmod 4$, we have
$$ f(p^r)=\begin{cases}4&r\text{ even}\\0&r\text{ odd}\end{cases}$$
(obtained from $\pm p^{r/2}$ and $\pm ip^{r/2}$ in the even case).

Remains the oddest of all primes, $2$:
$$ f(2^r)=4$$
with the odd case stemming from $\pm1 \pm i$.

Finally, for composite $n=\prod_j p_j^{r_j}$, we have $f(n)=\prod_jf(p_j^{r_j})$.